# Who proclaimed separation of science from philosophy?

Tags: science, philosophy

Historically (since 2500 years ago), [philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy) - "love of wisdom" in Greek - encompassed *all* intellectual endeavors, and [natural philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy) was seen as its part. However, these days the term [*science*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science) has supplanted "*natural philosophy*" and *scientists* are not considered to be *philosophers*.

I seem to recall that there was a watershed event in the second half of 19th century (circa 1870?) when a major (German?) scientist ([Helmholtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_von_Helmholtz)?) declaimed (at a major scientific convention?) something like

> Philosophers think that scientists are conceited and scientists think that philosophers are insane.

Alas, I have not been able to find a specific reference.

#### So, who/when/where said that?

**PS1**. The meaning of the phrase is that philosophers, employing their traditional scholarship, managed to learn zilch about how nature actually works, while scientists, employing the [scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method), managed to learn quite a lot.

**PS2**. [Asked](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14483/1940) on History of Science and Math as recommended in the comments.

**PS3**. According to Philipp Frank in ["The Origin of the Separation Between Science and Philosophy"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20023644):

> Kant stated bluntly that the observable facts of the physical world are completely and satisfactorily described and systematized by "science proper"; "philosophy proper" can never tell us anything about them.

He never mentions anything related to *my* question - i.e., a **blunt disparagement of philosophers by a scientist**.

Comment: This might be one of those questions that, while on-topic here, is more likely to get good answers over on [History of Science and Math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Indeed, the question has been asked and answered there: [When and why did people stopped using "natural philosophy" term and started using "science"?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7651)

Comment: @ccprog: related, but no cigar.

Comment: _Exact_ crossposting is suboptimal. Can you add slight variation o better match each site? // Title & body seem to ask different things? Title is about fields of study (and suggests to me a much earlier date), body seems to inquire about one specific aphorisms that _is about people in those fields (+their relationship to/or view of each other; and a late date)?_

Comment: Why do you think there was one definitive proclamation?  There often is a subtle drift of terminology, unperceived at the time, until a word has a new meaning, or has lost an old one.

Comment: Almost the exact words used here:["warum sowohl viele Philosophen die Naturwissenschaftler für beschränkt und eingebildet halten als auch viele Naturwissenschaftler keinen Sinn in der Philosophie erkennen können."](https://sedl.at/Philosophie/Wissenschaft), but 3rd hand 'quoting', ref'ing an internal lecture document [of a physicist doing philosophy](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/josef.tomiska/i_Publist.html)

Answer (score 2):

That would be Bacon and later Newton with rejectin of FINAL CAUSES , the very lifeblood of philosophy

a final cause is that for the sake of which a thing is changing. A seed's end is an adult plant. A sailboat's purpose is sailing. A ball at the top of a ramp will finally come to rest at the bottom....So Evolution just says E. does what it does , there is no real end or finality to what a man does or in accord with his essence/nature

Francis Bacon described the use of final causes within science as being irrelevant to scientific inquiry - they have "given men the occasion to stay upon these satisfactory and specious causes, to the great arrest aand prejudice of further discovery".

Reductionism is often the result of this reducing everything to the material and mathematically tractable. A GREAT and short example can be found in De Koninck's "The Lifeless World of Biology"
http://www.isnature.org/Files/DeKoninck_Lifeless_Biology.PDF

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).